# Best way to draw/show different circles in JLabels depending on an enum class

Tags: java, swing, enums, jlabel, geometry

I've got a 4x4 grid layout based on JLabels and want to display different circles in them. The color of the circles depends on an enum class which is providing three possible colors like blue, yellow and grey.

```
public enum State {
BLUE, YELLOW, GREY
}
```

I've never worked with drawing before, so I'm not really sure how to handle it. 
Maybe I would think of three different methodes like

```
if (myfield[x][y] == BLACK) { 
  //Draw a black circle inside the JLabel here
  //maybe open a new method for that
   } else if...
```

to draw each circle.

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: Each enum has an option to define methods and extra attributes for each of its items. Try this!

Comment: Inside the enum, each of its items will have an attribute rgb defining the color. Then instead of repeating the code for each of the States, you will have to call the method just once.